# Change Color of Label and Div Around Input + Label on Click

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

Thank you in advance! New to Javascript.

I need to develop custom checkboxes that sit inside a div, and when you click the label or checkbox the div's border and font color change. Thought I could do this with CSS, but I'm starting to think I need JS.

Here's my code so far:

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

div.label {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 23px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height:50px;
    width: 225px;
    text-align:center;
}

label {
    color:gray;
    line-height:50px;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2713";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-left:10px; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="label">
<input id="weekly" type="checkbox" name="lists[weekly]" value="True" />
<label for="weekly">Weekly Preview Email</label><br>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: js or with help of jquery??

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as it works! Also, just edited to note that the label is also inside the div with the checkbox. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want it in CSS? It [is possible](http://jsbin.com/riyog/2/edit)

Comment: If it's possible, sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with just CSS:

The checkbox needs to be directly before the first thing that you want to style. In your example it needs to be in front of `div.label`. For multiple divs in a page make sure to change each `for` and corresponding `id`.

`input:checked + div` will target only the div directly after an input that has been checked.

[Have a jsBin example!](http://jsbin.com/riyog/4/edit) (now with a tick)

[Here is the same example with multiple checkboxes and divs](http://jsbin.com/riyog/3/edit)

HTML

```
<input id="weekly" type="checkbox" name="lists[weekly]" value="True" />
<div class="label">    
<label for="weekly">Weekly Preview Email (click me)</label><br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + div {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    color: #F00;
}

input:checked + div:before {
    content: "\2713";
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, and looks like it works for what I need... However, the custom checkbox I styled now doesn't appear at all, and only the text/border colors are changing. Any way to retain my custom checkbox as well, inside the div?

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance here! I'm not sure if the checkbox is an image - it's this (I found it online):   content: "\2713";

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery,

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
        return $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked');
    });
});
```

This will add a "checked" class to the parent div. You can define CSS for the parent.

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mxq80pf6/).

**EDIT:** Based on the comment, added a style in CSS to color the label. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mxq80pf6/1/).

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I need! The only issue is I can't get the label text to change color...  Not sure why? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
$('.label').click(function(){debugger;
$(this).toggleClass("checked")


});
```

Adding a checked css class

```
.checked {
   border:1px solid black;
   color:red;
}
```

It will do what you want, change the border/text on checking/unchecking the checkbox or clicking the label.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ohdjj7h/1/)